# Visual studio + MySQL on Mac: Virtual Box vs Parallels

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, macos, parallel-processing, virtualbox

I am forced to finish my Windows project on Mac - Its a Visual Studio C# connected to MySQL database. I've installed it quite nicely on Virtual box and all looks fine (well... except the look of the VB itself, I can't change the screen resolution for some reasons so I use only about 50% of screen). 
When I told this to my friend, who is quite passionate about Macs he suggested me Parallels, and even offered his copy. While it looks nicer and in theory is "better" I am not really able to work properly on connection between VS and MySQL: when I'm trying to get through wizard to add data sources I either get error that system cannot connect to ODBC (yes, I've reinstalled connectors) or wizard proceeds, but disappears after pressing any button (i.e. while I'm trying to type "localhost").

have anyone had such problems with Parallels? Or should I try to work on Virtual Box and fix the screen problem (any hints on that would be appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Parallels with Visual Studio / SQL Server for over 4 years by now, and it works like a charm! If for whatever reason your virtual machine might get slow, I can recommend you to get some extra memory for your beloved Apple.

Especially when running Windows, Parallels has some fancy integration tools, which gives it some pro's in comparison to VirtualBox.

My current Mac has 8GB of internal memory with an SSD drive. I have assigned 4GB for my virtual machine. I don't notice any slow-downs on OSX, nor on the virtual machine. In fact, my Windows boots faster than one of my native Windows machines!

Comment: Its not the matter of speed: I have 8 GB of total ram and same as you I've assigned half of it to Windows. but my problem is with connection between Visual studio and Mysql that exists in Parallels but not on VB

Comment: Ah sorry - hard to miss, but I actually did miss that one.. Can you tell me if the MySQL instance is running on the virtual machine, or on the Mac? If it's running on the Mac you might consider changing your Parallels network settings - see http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/22249.htm for some explanation on this one.

Comment: No, its running on virtual machine, both on VB and parallel